# Get out a variable from a javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, document.write

I have this function (I didn't write it):

```
    <script>
      ab(function(r) {  
        var field_number = r.get('field_number'); 
        alert(field_number); 
      });
    </script>
```

Alert is working fine, so field_number is correct, but document.write doesn't work. I need to extract the value of field_number outside of the function, to make it work on other parts of the html:

```
<script>document.write(field_number);</script>
```

How can I get it out?
Thanks.

Comment: Depends. What does `ab` do? Is `ab` a function you can modify? Is there some reason you don't just use `field_number` in the callback?

Comment: I can't modify it. I just can get the field_number (if I would know how!)

Comment: What does `ab` do? Is there some reason you don't just use `field_number` in the callback?

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure what it does, it's not mine. I just want to retrieve the variable and use it in other places. I know it has to be an easy way to do it but I don't know much about how Javascript deals with variables.

Comment: `field_number` is scoped to your callback, you either need to define the `field_number` somewhere outside your `ab` callback or scope the rest of your code inside of your callback for it to have access to that value.

Comment: The variable is scoped to the function that is passed to `ab`. I assume `ab` accepts a callback because it's asynchronous. Why not just put your code inside the callback?

Comment: @user1689607 I've tried but document.write doesn't output anything inside that function

Comment: @troy I've tried to define it outside the function first, but that hasn't worked either. `var field_number = '';
ab(function(t) {  field_number = r.get('field_number'); });`

Comment: Are you attempting to write this value some where in the DOM? If so you don't want to use `document.write`.

Comment: Oh, that worked!! Yes, I can write from inside the function to an outside element. That's a great advance, maybe I can do my work with that. But I'm still intrigued about why I can't get that value out of the function. Anyway, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If it is not asynchronous call for `ab()` you can set global variable:

```
  <script>
      var field_number="";
      ab(function(r) {  
        field_number = r.get('field_number'); 
        alert(field_number); 
      });
      // you can use variable here
    </script>
```

Or you can return it from function and assign to variable then use it.

Comment: This is not working: `var field_number;
ab(function(r) {  field_number = r.get('field_number'); alert(field_number); });
document.write(field_number);` It is writing "Undefined" but alert does output the correct value.

Comment: alert outside of function instead of document.write()

Comment: If there's a callback, them most likely `ab` does some asynchronous code so the variable will still be `undefined` after the `ab` call.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and best way to do is:

```
<script>

var a="";    //global variable

    function process()
    {
        a=1;
    process_another(a)    //another function in which you want the value of a 

    }

    function process_another(a)
    {
        alert(a);   //value of a will be shown: 1 as it was in function process() 
        } 
          </script>
```